# C# VS generate Model from Database swaps Datatype

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have a C# Project where I use MaraidDB-Databases. I use the .NetFramework 4.5.2

The .edmx files are created from the database. Now, the Problem is, that in the Databases is a field called "duration" this field is Type Time, in one Database it´s DateTime. The EDMX-Designer changes the Types in VS from Time to DateTime and from DateTime to TimeSpan.

I integrated the Databases in my Project and it ran well for a while. But on one Point for some reason this Problem showed up and don´t go away with deleting the edmx files, clean up Project, rebuild Project and import the Database again.

I tried something like this but it doesn´t work.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4abd605-37a0-467f-93c7-bfe4a101612f/how-to-resolve-systemdatamappingexception?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Has anyone an Idea, what this Problem causes?

Comment: Start by opening up the database and checking the datatypes for each field.  Apparently the type in the database and the type in VS aren't matching; or a cell(s) in the database has the wrong type data and you will need to fix by manually going into the database and changing the data.

Comment: Yeah I thought about this. But should it not be, that VS has the same data types like the database not the other way round? Can´t I manually change the datatype in the classes?

Comment: Yes is should!!!  Otherwise you may get inconsistencies.  If you don't use the same types it is like using excel with General Formatting.  Often in excel numbers get changed to dates and dates get changed to numbers.

Comment: Hmm, but you don´t have an Idea why VS recognizes Time as DateTime and not as TimeSpan?

Comment: Yes.  It is guessing like excel does with general format.  That is why in VS with Data class you should always use parameters which define the type.

Comment: Ok understood. And how can I use Parameters there?

Comment: When reading you do not need parameters.  Only when writing.  When reading using the DataAdapter the adapter will automatically load the datatable with correct types.  I suspect when you did some sort of update you wrote wrong type to database and now is giving you errors.  What class are you using to connect to the MairaidDB-Database?

Comment: I use the MySqlConnector Net 6.9.8 and added the Databases just with ADO.Net Entitiy Data Model. And then I just use the Entitity classes in code. I use the entity framework 5.0.0

Comment: I looked at the oledb version of the Data Class last week and when type is null does no checking and returns object.  When type is found it does a conversion.  So when the database has a type declared the type gets converted in the driver then you have to make sure in your c# code you use the same type.

Comment: Ah okey thats interessting. So when I just work with the type VS generated, then it should be fine?

Comment: For reading from database yes.  Not for writing.

Comment: Ok good to know...the thing is, that I don´t even touch this field, it´s just there and I get a Mapping Exception for this field.

Comment: The DataTime must be null ( which is 1/1/01 since DateTime Object doesn't accept null).  So the driver is guessing that year 1 is a TimeSpan instead of a DateTime and converting to a Timespan.

Comment: Ok, I guess I found the Point the causing this issue. I have a few separate databases with the same tables in it and in one database, the duration field has an other datatype. So when I comment out the Entity for this database it works fine. Is it possible that the emdx has a problem with when different databases have the same class names and properties but one porperty in one class has another data type?